# Linear interpolation: reach moving destination regardless how fast it moves

Tags: math, game-engine, physics, lerp

I'm implementing a camera for a game and I'm using the LERP formula for smooth chasing. However, if the target moves fast enough, the camera can never reach it unless the `t` ([(1 - t) * v0 + t * v1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)) value is high enough, but that is exactly the problem: some targets might still move faster than the current `t` value.

This might lead to 2 problems:

1. The camera will never reach the object if it's super fast
2. The camera will very slowly reach the object, depending on it's
   current speed

How do I scale up my `t` when the delta distance (abs(`v1 - v0`)) gets lower, so that the camera will starts at a slow chasing rate and increases as it gets closer (therefore no targets could run away)?

Comment: I kinda managed to solve this by increasing `t` over time, as it will eventually reach `1` (guaranting to reach the target). If there's a better way to doing this, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are `v0` and `v1`? Can you give us a complete example?

Comment: @Beta v0 and v1 are points you want to interpolate on (start and end). You can check the formula's link above

Comment: Yes, but you have not explained how `v0`, `v1` and `t` correspond to the motions of the target and the camera. You have a target that starts at location **T0** with constant velocity **z**, and a camera that starts at location **C0**. *What do you want the camera to do?* Move at constant velocity to intercept the target? At a given time? Or at a given place? Or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "a given place", but anyways `v0` is the camera's position and `v1` is the target's. The `t` was a small factor that gave a nice smoothness, however if the target was moving, there were cases that `t` was low enough to reach `v1`. I solved it by using `t = min(t + SOME_CONSTANT_FACTOR, 1)`, that way `t` scales up to 1, which then the LERP would return the `v1`'s value at some point, reaching the moving object. However, I was looking for some formulas that wouldn't require to sum up `t` every camera tick (game loop).